# Rx combineLatest не понимаю почему ошибка

Tags: android, rxjava2

Пытаюсь создать комбинирующую функцию с помощью Rx. Делал так много раз никогда не было проблем.

```
    fun getCategories(): Observable<ArrayList<String>> {
    return Observable.combineLatest<ArrayList<String>,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            String,
            ArrayList<String>>(
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.animals)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.textures)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.buildings)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.nature)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.music)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.travel)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.sports)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.fashion)),
            Function8(::createList)
    )
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
}

private fun createList(
        url: String,
        url2: String,
        url3: String,
        url4: String,
        url5: String,
        url6: String,
        url7: String,
        url8: String
): ArrayList<String> {
    val categories = ArrayList<String>()
    categories.add(url)
    categories.add(url2)
    categories.add(url3)
    categories.add(url4)
    categories.add(url5)
    categories.add(url6)
    categories.add(url7)
    categories.add(url8)

    return categories
}
```

Но почему то студия ругается на combineLatest пишет что: None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied. Сегодня делал то же самое и все работало.

Comment: Build->Clean Project, 
File->Sync Project

Comment: пробовал. не помогает

Comment: Есть несколько перегруженных методом `Observable.combineLatest()`, принимающих разное кол-во аргументов. Но эти перегрузки поддерживают не любое число аргументов. Если у вас много аргументов, то используйте перегрузку, принимающую массив источников данных, вместо отдельного источника в качестве одного из аргументов.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается можно не прописывать тип входящих и возвращаемых данных. Поменял на вот такую запись. Работает:

```
   fun getCategories(): Observable<ArrayList<String>> {
   return Observable.combineLatest(
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.animals)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.textures)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.buildings)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.nature)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.music)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.travel)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.sports)),
            apiRepository.getCategories(context.getString(R.string.fashion)),
            Function8(::createList)
    )
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
```

}